# Dynamically arrange columns in a table

Tags: html, backbone-views, rivets.js

What I am trying to do is, I have a table made of divs. total 8 columns . first eight columns in a div shows the heading, and rest columns shows the content

```
<div id="student-table">
<div id="student-table-header">
<div class="student-table-col-header">{label.header1}</div>
<div class="student-table-col-header">{label.header2}</div>
<div class="student-table-col-header">{label.header3}</div>
<div class="student-table-col-header">{label.header4}</div>
</div>
<div id="student-table-body">
<div rv-each-studentlist="studentlist">
<div class="student-table-col-body">{studentlist.name}</div>
<div class="student-table-col-body">{studentlist.age}</div>
<div class="student-table-col-body">{studentlist.subject}</div>
<div class="student-table-col-body">{studentlist.mark}</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

So I need to provide a configuration from back end, that is a specific order. And I want to arrange the column in the order of configuration. So what should i do for this. Any lead? Should I use templating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea on which configuration structure you are using. Lets say if you can have a simple json structure like as shown below then things will be pretty easy

```
{
 "tableHeader": [ 
                  { "headerValue": "Name", "headerKey": "name" },
                  { "headerValue": "Age", "headerKey": "age" },
                  { "headerValue": "Subject", "headerKey": "subject" },
                  { "headerValue": "Mark", "headerKey": "mark" }
                ],
 "tableBody":   [
                  { "name": "manu", "age": 22, "subject": "maths", "mark": 125 },
                  { "name": "john", "age": 25, "subject": "maths", "mark": 111 },
                  { "name": "arun", "age": 28, "subject": "maths", "mark": 222 }
                  :
                  :
                  :
                ]
}
```

The table will generate with the column order specified within the tableHeader array, say if you have the `Name, Age, Subject, Mark` as the order then table column and the body details will be generated in that order.

In the html use rivet formatter for formatting the details like as show below

```
<div id="student-table">
    <div id="student-table-header">
        <div class="student-table-col-header" rv-each-headers="studentDetails.tableHeader">
            <p>{ headers.headerValue }</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="student-table-body" rv-each-students="studentDetails.tableBody">
        <div class="student-table-col-body" rv-each-header="studentDetails.tableHeader">
             <span>{ students | formatDetails header.headerKey }</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Foramtter function will be

```
rivets.formatters.formatDetails = function (studentDetails, headerKey) {
   return studentDetails[headerKey];
};
```

**[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L1ovrsds/)** - change the tableHeader json order and test

Comment: Thanks da, And one more thing. If I have inner divs in <div class="student-table-col-body" , what should i do?

Comment: hoi,....I am not getting you, tell me what you are trying to achieve or just give me a jsfiddle on the same.